# Flutter - card_scanner - IOS build issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

The package works on Android. But on iOS I am still not able to build with the latest version.
when I try to build the application using the package  card_scanner ^0.2.0+3, I get the error:

!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (GoogleDataTransport, GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport, and [GoogleUtilitiesComponents)

I have created a fresh flutter project and imported the plugin with latest version, but when I try to run the app with no changes in main.dart file, it shows the error as mentioned and attached in the screenshot

You can find the plugin in here: https://pub.dev/packages/card_scanner

[image: screenshot]